# Nash-like table for a full 9 players table?

Tags: texas-hold-em, probability, no-limit, statistics

I'm wondering, is there anything like the Nash Equilibrium that I can use to know when to go all in if my blinds a low in a full 9 players table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should go all-in with being short stacked is not that simple. There are so many different variables that a chart could only be used as a reference.

A quick google "push fold charts 9 max", gave a couple good images and this site: https://floattheturn.com/wp/pushfold/. But again, only use this as a reference.

If you want to go more in depth in all of this, I would recommend you to purchase icmizer 2. This is in my opinion the best program to teach you about all this. One month costs 15-25 dollars and could teach you a lot.